# Best way to collect or log kernel events?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, monitoring

I am trying to collect logs for specific kernel events.

The first solution that came to my mind is to:

1. Insert `printk`s to specific points in the kernel code,
2. Boot the kernel (with QEMU/KVM? whatever)
3. Periodically poll `dmesg` outputs, select interested messages and store them.

It will work, but I don't believe this is the best way to do such tasks :-(

What are the good ways of collecting kernel events (and logs)?

Comment: This [breakdown of all log files](https://superuser.com/a/734328/1270397) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: `Periodically poll dmesg outputs` Why periodically?? Newer dmesg have `-H` option, but just `cat /dev/kmsg`